# See response in console preview tab, console log returns undefined ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am making a very simple jquery ajax call to a symfony controller which returns some html that I will append into a div. I have done this a lot, but never come across an issue like this. I can see the response coming back from the server in the preview tab of the console. I can also see it in the response tab of the network console. However, when I console log the response from the controller, I get undefined. I have gone as far as to copy and paste the response from the preview tab into a variable and log what I need and it works just fine. The JSON response is completely valid. It's not throwing any errors, nor is the ajax call triggering the error function after the call is made. Everything appears to work perfectly with the exception of making any use of the data returned.

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    data: {
        from: from,
        to: to,
        credential: credential
    },
    success: function(data) {               
        console.log(data); // undefined

    }
});
```

here is an example of the response:

```
{"html":"<div><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"add-webinars\" value=\"\"><\/div><div><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"add-webinars\" value=\"\"><\/div>"}
```

Undefined every single time and it's driving me a bit crazy. Anyone have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Is this cross domain?

Comment: If it were (and was the problem), he wouldn't getting to success

Comment: You'll have to follow this through the jQuery source to see where it's getting lost. One option would be to test this without jQuery to narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: It is, but I have been making them in the same controller using almost the same jquery code and it's been working just fine. it's just this one that is not working, which is why it's so frustrating

Comment: I'm using the xdomain.js script to get the cross domain to work. Either way, they're to a server that I have control of instead of a service that is external.

Comment: The success callback takes two other arguments (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Try adding those and console logging them, just as an experiment I guess.

Comment: I logged the arguments and the other two were right, but the response was still undefined.

Comment: rule out jquery is step one. Use plain old xhr

Comment: Made a good ol' fashioned xmlhttprequest and logged the responseText...undefined

Comment: If you're using xDomain, then the request should be getting made via an iframe. Have you been able to see the iframe in your dom inspector? I would have expected you to see some kind of error or timeout in the console if this is failing, but it's likely xDomain is just failing to throw an error.

Comment: Enable debug https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain#xdomaindebug--false

Comment: I know the timeout error you're talking about and this isn't the case(this time, though I have ran into that before). I enabled debug and it doesn't seem to be throwing any errors. It created the iframe and does everything it is supposed to do. I don't know why I would be able to see the response in the preview tab of the network when I make the request but not have access to it in the success callback.

Comment: At this point you've ruled out your code and pretty much pinned the problem as being with xDomain.js. Maybe open and issue? There seems to be a similar one open specifically for IE9

Comment: hey@JeffNeal. Did you find the solution for this? I'm facing the same problem and it is driving me crazy. I'm using xdomain.min.js like you and getting the response in preview and network tabs but not in console.

Comment: No, I never found exactly the solution. But I narrowed it down to the fact I was testing from my local machine. I assume thats the issue because it works once I deployed it live. Hope this helps.